# How to access database data when exception occur?

Tags: perl, dbi, dbix-class

I have next code:

```
my $savepoint =  $c->db->txn_scope_guard;
return $self->render( 'subnet/create',  error => [ create => $@ ],
    servers =>  $self->rows( 'Server' )->lookup,
) unless $subnet =  eval{ $self->rows( 'Subnet' )->create( $subnet ) };
$savepoint->commit;
```

Here `rows` is Mojolicious helper which provides access to data.

```
sub model {
    my( $c, $table_name ) =  (shift,shift);

    return $c->db->resultset( $table_name );
}
```

And `->db` is also helper:

```
sub db { return $schema
    //=  DBIx::Class::Schema->connect( $DB->{ DSN },  @$DB{ qw/ USER PASS / },  {
        AutoCommit => 1,
        RaiseError => 1,
        quote_char => '"',
    })
});
```

When I create `$subnet` and unique constraint occurs (here has no matter which constraint occur, actually in case of any exception) I got the error:

```
DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_dbh_execute(): DBI Exception: DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block [for Statement "SELECT "me"."id", "me"."hostname" FROM "servers" "me" ORDER BY hostname"] at ...
```

This is when I catch exception with `eval{ ... }` the current transaction is aborted and I can not do `$self->rows( 'Server' )->lookup`

**Is there a way to access server data after exception occur?**

Comment: Why don't you do the lookup before the create?

Comment: because I do not require to lookup data when user `POST` his selection. I require lookup only when rendering form `subnet/create`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found the answer, because read error message more carefully:

> ... commands ignored until end of transaction block

So I force the end for transaction block when exception occur:

```
$c->db->txn_rollback;
```

The code:

```
my $savepoint =  $c->db->txn_scope_guard;
unless( $subnet =  eval{ $self->rows( 'Subnet' )->create( $subnet ) } ) {
    my $e = $@; # $@ may be changed before `create => $@`
    undef $savepoint; # Or the same: $c->db->txn_rollback;     
    return $self->render( 'subnet/create',  error => [ create => $e ],
        servers =>  $self->rows( 'Server' )->lookup,
    );
}
$savepoint->commit;
```

Comment: You should add a reference to that quote, so others can read its context.

Comment: You should save $@ in some other variable immediately in the unless block; if you put other code first it might end up cleared or changed

Comment: Thanks, missed that bit.

Comment: This is a situation where `Try::Tiny` would help you, since it does the `$@`-saving etc.